# Get the last index number VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, indexing, inputstream, outputstream

I'm a beginner in vb.net. How can I get the last index number in vb.net?

For example:
I have a 3 text files, which has a different filenames.

Everytime the application restarts, it will continue with the last index number.

For example:
Filename1 previoulsy, reopened the application again, then it will continue to filename2.

My problem is, everytime I restart the application, the filename1 is always opened, it not continue to filename2.

How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: How can I get the index_number?

Comment: Use `My.Settings` to save something so small between app runs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you restart your application the variables are re-initialized. You probably are using an integer for the index and you have it initialized to 1. You need to store the state of the index to persistent memory (like a file or a database) then when your application is closing, or at some other time. Then when you start up your application read the file or database for the last index number.

Answer (score 1):

You can read your last file and create next by incrementing last index.

```
Dim newFileIndex as Integer = Directory.GetFiles().Select(
    Function(full)
        Dim nameParts() As String = full.Split("\", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim name As String = nameParts(nameParts.Length - 1) 
        name = name.Substring("filename".Length, name.LastIndexOf(".") - "filename".Length)
        ' At this point you have your file number.
        ' for example, if your file is "filename100.txt" the variable [name] now has 100 in it
        Return Convert.ToInt32(name)
    End Function).Max() + 1

   'Now you can create new filename
   filename = "filename" & newFileIndex.ToString() & ".txt"
```